# Create dynamic check box and radio buttons in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

```
Basically I am creating a full dynamic form which has text boxes, check boxes, etc.

When I try to add this code in a page where `EnableViewState="false"` it doesn't work but it works fine on a page where `EnableViewState="true"`. 

But I want it to work on this (`EnableViewState="false"`) page. How do I do this?
```

Basic idea of doing this is to create a dynamic page on which I can add as many controls as I can with just clicking one button. Controls can repeat.
         Panel pnlTextBox;
        protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
            //Create a Dynamic Panel
            pnlTextBox = new Panel();
            pnlTextBox.ID = "pnlTextBox";
            pnlTextBox.BorderWidth = 1;
            pnlTextBox.Width = 300;
            this.form1.Controls.Add(pnlTextBox);

            //Create a LinkDynamic Button to Add TextBoxes

            //Recreate Controls
            RecreateTextBoxControls("txtDynamic", "TextBox");
            RecreateDDLControls("ddlDynamic", "DropDownList");

    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    //  /*  int i=Convert.ToInt32(DropDown1.SelectedValue.ToString());
    //    if (i == 1)
    //    {*/
          int cnt = FindOccurence("txtDynamic");
    CreateTextBox("txtDynamic-" + Convert.ToString(cnt + 1));
    //  /*  }
    //    else if (i == 2)
    //    {
    //        int cnt = FindOccurence("ddlDynamic");
    //        CreateDropDownList("ddlDynamic-" + Convert.ToString(cnt + 1));
    //    }
    //    else if (i == 3)
    //    {

    //    }
    //    else if (i == 4)
    //    {

    //    }
    //    else if (i == 5)
    //    {
    //    }
    //    else if (i == 6)
    //    {

    //    }
    //    else
    //    {
    //        Console.Write("Bawa ji ka thullu");

    //    }
    //    */

    }
    private int FindOccurence(string substr)
    {
        string reqstr = Request.Form.ToString();
        return ((reqstr.Length - reqstr.Replace(substr, "").Length) /                                                                                                                                                        ....substr.Length);
    }
    private void RecreateTextBoxControls(string ctrlPrefix, string ctrlType)
    {
        string[] ctrls = Request.Form.ToString().Split('&');
        int cnt = FindOccurence(ctrlPrefix);
        if (cnt > 0)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= cnt; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ctrls.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ctrls[i].Contains(ctrlPrefix + "-" + k.ToString()) &&                                                    
                    !ctrls[i].Contains("EVENTTARGET"))
                      {
                        string ctrlID = ctrls[i].Split('=')[0];

                        if (ctrlType == "TextBox")
                        {
                            CreateTextBox(ctrlID);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
      private void RecreateDDLControls(string ctrlPrefix, string ctrlType)
      {
        string[] ctrls = Request.Form.ToString().Split('&');
        int cnt = FindOccurence(ctrlPrefix);
        if (cnt > 0)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= cnt; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ctrls.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ctrls[i].Contains(ctrlPrefix + "-" + k.ToString()) && 
                   !ctrls[i].Contains("EVENTTARGET"))
                    {
                        string ctrlID = ctrls[i].Split('=')[0];

                        if (ctrlType == "DropDownList")
                        {
                            CreateDropDownList(ctrlID);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreateDropDownList(string ID)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
        ddl.ID = ID;
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", ""));
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("One", "1"));
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Two", "2"));
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Three", "3"));
        ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
        ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(OnSelectedIndexChanged);
        pnlTextBox.Controls.Add(ddl);

        Literal lt = new Literal();
        lt.Text = "<br />";
        pnlTextBox.Controls.Add(lt);
    }
    private void CreateTextBox(string ID)
    {

        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = ID;
        txt.AutoPostBack = true;
        txt.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnTextChanged);
        pnlTextBox.Controls.Add(txt);

        Literal lt = new Literal();
        lt.Text = "<br />";
        pnlTextBox.Controls.Add(lt);
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you keep it true then?

Comment: I want to make a complete dynamic form, for that purpose I need to add all controls, some controls allows me with true state and some are working with false state.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me know what Ph is?
The same code works for me. What I did is I created a panel with the name Ph and then added the CbxList to that panel i.e. Ph

Here is the code

```
*CheckBoxList CbxList = new CheckBoxList();
    TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
    RadioButtonList rbList = new RadioButtonList();
    rbList.Items.Add("First Radio Button List");
    rbList.Items.Add("Second Radio Button List");
    rbList.Items.Add("Third Radio Button List");
    rbList.Items.Add("Fourth Radio Button List");
    rbList.Items.Add("Fifth Radio Button List");

    RadioButton rbTest = new RadioButton();
    rbTest.Text = "Simple Radio Button";
    txtBox.Text = "Simple Text Box";
    CbxList.ID = "Cbx";
    for (int i = 0; i < intCount; i++)
    {
        CbxList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Convert.ToChar(i + 65).ToString(), Convert.ToChar(i + 65).ToString()));
    }

    //Adding controls to Panel

    ph.Controls.Add(rbTest);

    ph.Controls.Add(CbxList);

    ph.Controls.Add(rbList);

    ph.Controls.Add(txtBox);

    ViewState["ListCreated"] = false;*
```

Comment: This is a panel in which we are adding chkbox. It also works for me when I only add chkbox but in my case i need to add chkboxes radio buttons textboxes etc in same panel. in this case it does't work.

Comment: Can you please share your code here so that I can get better idea?

Comment: Please have a look at the above code. This works for me. I think so what are missing is Adding Controls to the panel.

Comment: I have added the code above in the question which is my idea for doing this. Thanks Nasir Khan if you could help me out in this.

Comment: http://formbuilder.eminencedigital.com/formbuilder/forms/index    you can see what I am going to make